# Sending AJAX POST request to Express

Tags: javascript, ajax, express, ejs

I have two questions. First one is, I don't know what I'm doing wrong when sending a POST request using AJAX. I am geting results back but userSrc parameter that I send is undefined.

How to send parameter so Express can read it using req.query and use it as a parameter for searching?

Here is the code:

Jquery:

```
$(function() {
    
    $("#userSrc").keyup( function () {
        let dInput = $("#userSrc").val();
        console.log(dInput);
      $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
        url: '/quicksearch',
        data : {userSrc :dInput},
        
        success: function(result) {
          let html = '';
          console.log(result);
          result.each(element =>{
            console.log(element);
            html += "<h2>" + element.Title +"</h2>";
            $("#result").html(html);
          });
          
          
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Express:

```
app.post("/quicksearch", (req, res) => {
  let search = req.query.userSrc;
  console.log(search);

  Recent.findOne({
    Title: search
  }, (err, foundData) => {
    if (err || foundData == null) {
      fetch("http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=" + search + "&apikey=b322e698")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          console.log("API RESPONSE");
          console.log(data.Search);
          res.send({
            result: data.Search
          });
        });
    } else {

      
      console.log("Found Local");
      res.send( {
        result: foundData
      });
    }
  });
```

The second question which I have is, how to implement the result that I receive back since I've tried using Object.keys and ForEach. I am not sure how to get to the result.Title.

```
{result: Array(7)}
    result: Array(7)
    0: {Title: "Undefined", Year: "2006", imdbID: "tt1436480", Type: "movie", Poster: "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTgzNzkxMzk5Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTQ2MzA2MDE@._V1_SX300.jpg"}
    1: {Title: "The Undefined", Year: "2013", imdbID: "tt3271334", Type: "movie", Poster: "N/A"}
    2: {Title: "Viet Costas - Citizenship: Undefined", Year: "2014", imdbID: "tt3838986", Type: "movie", Poster: "N/A"}
    3: {Title: "A Love Undefined", Year: "2015", imdbID: "tt4955578", Type: "movie", Poster: "N/A"}
    4: {Title: "Artist Undefined", Year: "2015", imdbID: "tt5190590", Type: "movie", Poster: "N/A"}
    5: {Title: "Undefined", Year: "2014", imdbID: "tt5581814", Type: "movie", Poster: "N/A"}
    6: {Title: "Undefined: A Muslim-American Musical", Year: "2017", imdbID: "tt7178924", Type: "movie", Poster: "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BODMwYTE1ZG…jk0ZmZhXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzI4NTUyNjE@._V1_SX300.jpg"}
    length: 7
    __proto__: Array(0)
    __proto__: Object
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The express handler is getting the [query parameters](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.query) in the URL. Those are characters after the `?` in the URL, for example, `/quicksearch?search=text` then `req.query` would be `{ search: "text" }`.

You want to read the [request body](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.body). That can be done by `req.body`. Make sure you add the [`body-parser`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/body-parser) middleware in your express app. Include the middleware:

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
app.use(urlencodedParser);
```

Now in your route handlers you have access to `req.body`.

Your `forEach` is good, but it seems you're doing it on the wrong variable. In your JavaScript, the `result` contains the whole body of your response. Your array is in `result.result`. Rewrite for your JavaScript:

```js
$(function() {
    $("#userSrc").keyup(function() {
        let dInput = $("#userSrc").val();
        console.log(dInput);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/quicksearch',
            data: {
                userSrc: dInput
            },
            success: function(response) { // response is the whole body
                let html = '';
                console.log(response.result);
                response.result.each(element => {
                    console.log(element);
                    html += "<h2>" + element.Title + "</h2>";
                    $("#result").html(html);
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```